# Creating table Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:text="my name is Tarzan and i lives in Amazon Jungle. I want an android phone." android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="my name is Mowgly and i lives in Amazon Jungle. I want an android phone." android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</TableRow>
```

I have a table with two columns and I put TextViews in both.. I stretch the second column.. but, when I set the long text in both TextViews, the table stretch over the limit of phone so I can't see that.. it just same if I set the table layout with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.. what should I do?

Comment: What you want if the text is long how should it will display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:maxWidth="100dip"`.. add such a tag in your textView..